# pytorch: calculating loss function for multi label text classification

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using pytorch with transformers to use a trained bert model. while I am calculating the loss function. I am getting a error regarding different sizes and it put me off for a while now. Here is the whole [Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mtjzQbdVgPtTgAWDAYUVkuIutaH25qGs?usp=sharing). Here is the error:

```
ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([32, 14])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([24576, 14]))
```

please make sure you scroll through the notebook if you have any question.

Comment: I dont know what causes the error but it looks like the model does take in a batch of size 32 as input but the first dim of the output batch isnt 32. I think something happens in the model. Maybe you should take a better look at what ```AutoModel``` does exactly. Why do you take the first element of the output (```logits = outputs[0]```)?

Comment: @TheodorPeifer This is the first time I use pytorch and I was simply following this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/transformers-for-multilabel-classification-71a1a0daf5e1). there were taking only the first output which I dont understand either why!